# What’s the Biblical Basis for ex opere operato?

Tags: catholicism, sacraments, anglicanism, ex-opere-operato

[Ex Opere Operato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_opere_operato) is a theological claim that a sacrament is efficacious by the nature of it being a sacrament, not the minister or recipient. But what is the biblical basis for this idea (if any?)?

Comment: Answers to this question should come from a background that both understand sacraments and does not reject this theological statement.  A Biblical Basis question always assumes in a positive light the claims made in the question, it's not up for debate here.

Comment: As someone who understands sacraments and agrees with this theological statement, I don't think you are going to find a Biblical basis.

Comment: @DJClayworth Wanna bet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ex opere operato" (literally "from the work having been worked") is a Catholic phrase to describe the efficacy of Sacraments. It is often contrasted with "ex opere operantis" ("from the work of the working one", i.e. the minister/recipient).

Historical background: This term was developed in part as a response to the Donatist controversy. The Donatists considered acts done by the Traditores (those who handed over the scared things, usually Scriptures, to the Roman authorities during the persecution) sinful and invalid unless they repented and were re-baptized or re-ordained. Thus, they declared that all sacred acts must be done by faultless ministers.

The Biblical basis for this concept derives from where we see evidence that the sacraments are not mere signs of grace or faith (which would point to a purely human act) but actual occurrences of grace, since grace can only be given by God.

For example:

- [John 3:5](https://www.drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drb&bk=50&ch=3&l=5-#x) "Jesus answered: Amen, amen I say to thee, unless a man be born again of water and the Holy Ghost, he cannot enter into the kingdom of God."
- [Titus 3:5](https://www.drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drb&bk=63&ch=3&l=5-#x) "Not by the works of justice, which we have done, but according to his mercy, he saved us, by the laver of regeneration, and renovation of the Holy Ghost"
- [Acts 8:17](https://www.drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drb&bk=51&ch=8&l=17-#x) "Then they laid their hands upon them, and they received the Holy Ghost."
- [John 6:55-56](https://www.drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drb&bk=50&ch=6&l=55-#x) "He that eateth my flesh, and drinketh my blood, hath everlasting life: and I will raise him up in the last day. For my flesh is meat indeed: and my blood is drink indeed."
  (for additional details, see [Sacraments](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/13295a.htm))

These verses all contrast a work which a human does (eat, lay hands upon, baptize/be baptized) with material substances with an act that only God can do (salvation, indwelling of the Holy Spirit).

We might additionally look at [I Corinthians 3:4-7](https://www.drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drb&bk=53&ch=3&l=4-#x):

> For while one saith, I indeed am of Paul; and another, I am of Apollo; are you not men? What then is Apollo, and what is Paul. The ministers of him whom you have believed; and to every one as the Lord hath given. I have planted, Apollo watered, but God gave the increase.  Therefore, neither he that planteth is any thing, nor he that watereth; but God that giveth the increase.

Paul is criticizing the contention among the Corinthians for adhering to the "minister of [Christ]" who brought them to faith. He points out that God is the one who gives the grace ("the increase").

Lastly, Aquinas in discussing whether God alone or the minister as well works inwardly for the Sacramental effect cites Romans 8:33:

> It is written (Romans 8:33): "God that justifieth." Since, then, the inward effect of all the sacraments is justification, it seems that God alone works the interior sacramental effect. - [ST III Q64.A1](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/4064.htm)

Comment: You were wise to bet

Comment: The basic idea for all Catholic doctrine is that all Catholic doctrine is at least virtually if not formally/materially present in Scripture; that is, there is always some part of Scripture which points to or suggests the doctrine even if it doesn't spell it out.

Comment: material sufficiency ftw

Comment: material sufficiency?

Comment: all Catholic doctrines are at the very least found implicitly in the scriptures

Comment: Ah yes. I slightly misspoke above when I used materially. More correctly, Catholic doctrine is present virtually if not formally meaning the material of Scripture contains the underlying pieces which make up the formal doctrine